# Why are there positive and negative values of $\omega$ for which resonance occurs?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The question I'm having trouble with is 'determine the value(s) $\omega$ for which resonance occurs for the differential equation $q''+20q=100\sin(\omega t)$'.

So I know the first step is to consider the homogeneous part first ($q''+20q=0$). Next, considering the Characteristic Equation, $\lambda^2$ + $20$ = $0$, $\lambda = \pm 2\sqrt{5}i$. This means the real general solution for the homogeneous part is $$q_H(t)=A\cos(2\sqrt{5}t)+B\sin(2\sqrt{5}t)$$

The next step is to solve the inhomogeneous part. So if I were to choose $\omega=2\sqrt{5}$, resonance would occur, and so I rejected the negative $\lambda$ solution. However, the answers to my question state that the solution I rejected is also a value of $\omega$ that causes resonance. I rejected the negative solution as it would change the original differential equation as $100\sin(-2\sqrt{5}t) = -100\sin(2\sqrt{5}t)$.

My question is, why is the negative $\lambda$ value viable even if the original differential equation changes?

Comment: (FWIW, the characteristic equation is $\lambda^{2} + 20 = 0$, not $\lambda^{2} + 20\lambda = 0$. ;) Not sure I understand what you're asking. Is it that when $\omega = -2\sqrt{5}$ the ODE appears to become $q'' + q = -\sin(\omega t)$, which differs from  what was given...? If so, the resolution is that equation _doesn't_ pick up a minus sign on the right; it reads $q'' + 20q = \sin(\omega t)$, with $\omega = -2\sqrt{5}$.

Comment: Is that really it? Thank you! My lecturer wasn't very clear when he taught this.

Comment: That's just trigonometry. :) (If you like, signs in an expression can"hide" in unexpected places.)

Answer (score 0):

The solution of $\lambda^2$ + $20$ = $0$ is $\lambda = \pm j 2\sqrt{5}$ (purely imaginary). You can easily verify (by substituting) that both $Ae^{j 2\sqrt{5}t}$ and $Be^{-j 2\sqrt{5}t}$ solve the equation.

In general, since the coefficients of the differential equation are **real** constants, the imaginary solutions are always complex conjugate pairs.